# Can I patent a process in US being from another country?

Tags: patentability, process, us

sorry if this question is too stupid or something, but couldn't find the answer anywhere.

Basically, there are 2 (conditional) questions in one:

**1. can I file to patent a process in US?**

**2. if so: can I file for a patent being from another country?**

## Context

I tried to file for a patent in my country (Argentina). However, law in my country indicates that I can't file processes (including software) or flows comprised of different elements. Instead, I had to file for **Intellectual Property**.

Now, the system I'm trying to patent uses already known technologies (plus new software) in order to create a new process flow that is completely original. **Simply put:** it's an app that connects to a certain governmental area in a very special way to perform a whole new process  via AI. The system itself is very useful for the community and replaces an existing process with less than 5% of the cost, less human power and accuracy increased by 20x at least.

**In short:** exception made of software, all elements exists, only that I want to use them in a particular way *(dealing with governments, there's a whole legal side to it, of course, but it has to be considered on a one-by-one basis, so I don't care for that on this question, just assume everything is fine on that side)* .

While right now I have no hurry to patent this on another country, I want to cover all bases with this since there's quite an investment (pretty high, at least for me).  And filing for a patent on US would make this a lot simpler than patenting this on every country.

Also, I'm aware flow systems can be patented. A good example is [**Uber**](https://www.quora.com/Does-Uber-have-any-patents): **all the technologies and systems for their patents existed before Uber**, they just patented **a way to use them** (*in an extremely abstract way*).

Hence my questions: **can I patent something like this in US?**

Comment: We have an answer to 2. Somewhere around here I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. Phrasing this as if your invention were a thing, most patent claims are made of of existing "parts". How the parts are arranged and coupled relative to each other to function is usually what makes something novel and non-obvious. This is also true for a process. You could have an obvious arrangement of old steps or you could have a non-obvious arrangement of old things. And, after Alice, etc., you could have a great non-obvious invention that is deemed to be abstract without "something more" and then no patent.

Anyone can file for a U.S. patent. By international treat countries cannot treat outsiders any differently than their citizens and residents.